# Función Python para Anagramas en Lista

Tags: python

Necesito crear una función que permita leer una lista con palabras y si hay anagramas en la lista, es necesario eliminarlos de la lista y mostrar cuáles son.
Intenté esto hasta ahora y está funcionando me dice cuales son anagramas, pero es muy importante eliminar los anagramas de la lista y no se como hacerlo o si derectamente tengo que cambiar todo mi codigo.

```
in_list = ['casa','roma','perla','saca','mora','regla']
list_anagram = []

    for i in range(0, len(in_list) - 1):
        if sorted(in_list[i]) not in list_anagram:
            for j in range(i + 1, len(in_list)):
                isanagram = (sorted(in_list[i]) == sorted(in_list[j]))
                if isanagram:
                    list_anagram.append(sorted(in_list[i]))
                    print(f'{in_list[i]} = {in_list[j]} Is an ANAGRAM')
                else:
                    print(f'{in_list[i]} != {in_list[j]} Is Not an ANAGRAM')
```

Agradezco toda la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sin cambiar mucho tu codigo, digo, si ya guardas una lista de las palabras que son anagramas, que te costaria hacer una lista de las palabras que no son anagramas ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias!, esa idea me aclara un montón! y voy a revisar bien la plataforma, soy nuevo , gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Un consejo importante: nunca elimines elementos de una lista mientras la recorres. Para empezar, cambias el largo de la lista, pero como el rango del `for` quedó fijo al empezar, vas a tener una excepción por índice fuera de rango.

La manera correcta de trabajar es creando una nueva lista a partir de la primera.

Aplicando tu método, al examinar una nueva palabra (como "casa"), la descomponemos en sus letras, que reordenamos alfabéticamente, volviendo a juntar en su *code*.

Así, "casa" se transforma en "aacs". Cualquier otra palabra que tenga el mismo *code*, será una anagrama.

Usaremos un diccionario indexado por *code* que tenga como valor la primera palabra encontrada con ese *code*.

El proceso se reduce a recorrer la `in_list`, calcular el *code* para cada palabra y ver si está o no en el diccionario.

Al terminar el proceso, los valores del diccionario son todas las palabras no repetidas.

```
in_list = ['casa','roma','perla','saca','mora','regla']
anagramas = {}

for palabra in in_list:
    code = ''.join(sorted(palabra))
    if code in anagramas:
        print(f'{anagramas[code]} = {palabra} Is an ANAGRAM')
    else:
        anagramas[code] = palabra
        print(f'{palabra} Is Not an ANAGRAM')

list_anagram = list(anagramas.values())
print(list_anagram)
```

produce:

```
casa Is Not an ANAGRAM
roma Is Not an ANAGRAM
perla Is Not an ANAGRAM
casa = saca Is an ANAGRAM
roma = mora Is an ANAGRAM
regla Is Not an ANAGRAM
['casa', 'roma', 'perla', 'regla']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!, es justo lo que quería hacer pero tenía conceptos erroneos!, me salvaste! ;)

Comment: Bueno, si esta respuesta es la que te ayudó, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Así es como expresamos agradecimiento aquí :)